# How to parse JSON object at server side?

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing

I am trying to send data to a server (local rest API) from react using post request, if i send an object like this:

`{key:"value"}`

then i get this at the server:

`{ '{"key":"value"}': '' }`

It's converting the whole object into key-value pair.
How can i solve this issue?

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/animals', JSON.stringify(data))
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
  });
```

If I don't stringify, then I get an empty object at the server, but if I do stringify, then I get this sort of object as mentioned above. Is there any way to convert it back to a normal object?

Comment: What does `data` look like? Looking at the [docs for axios](https://designrevision.com/react-axios/#post-requests), it looks like you're supposed to be sending a JavaScript object, not a string -- so it's probably something wrong with your `data` object.

Comment: Is your server javascript based? `JSON.parse(data)` should work then, but normally you should be able to send JavaScript objects.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown data is a simple object like { price: "500", weight: "50" } but if i dont stringify then i get an empty object at the backend.

Comment: Check out this GH Issue and see if it helps -- looks like some weird behavior with axios itself: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1195

Comment: It looks like the server expects to get data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, not `application/json`. Why? `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data looks like `key1=value1&key2=value2&...`. But values are optional, so `key1&key2=value2` works too. You are sending `{"key":"value"}` which to the server looks like a key without a value. Since it looks like you have control over the server, change the server implementation to parse the request body as JSON instead. How to do that depends on the framework you are using on the server.

Comment: @FelixKling i am using node but if i parse the req.body then it gives error 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' which means i dont need to parse. i am just stuck here, even tried fetch method and i have same problem with that as well.

Comment: `req.body` is already the parsed body, i.e. it is already an object. When you are processing it in your request handler it is already "too late". You have to hook into the process that does the parsing. If you are using express.js: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html (use the JSON parser).

Comment: @FelixKling I used bodyParser.json() instead of urlencoded and it works now. Thank you Felix you always help.

Comment: You're welcome! :) I copied my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the server expects to get data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, not `application/json`.

Why?

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data looks like

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&....
```

But values are optional, so

```
key1&key2=value2
```

works too.

You are sending `{"key":"value"}` which to the server looks like a key without a value. Since it looks like you have control over the server, change the server implementation to parse the request body as JSON instead. How to do that depends on the framework you are using on the server.

If you are using [express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html), use `bodyParser.json()`. Alternatively send the data `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded, not as JSON, as suggested by Chinedu.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a POST request with axios

```
axios.post('/user', {
 firstName: 'Fred',
 lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
 console.log(error);
});
```

Can you try constructing the data you want to send as the above exam, send to your api and see if the dummy data comes. No json parse or stringfy needed.
Are you using body-parser middleware in your nodejs express app?

Comment: yes it was actually a problem with body-parser, i was using bodyParser.urlencoded instead of bodyParser.json(). It works now!